# Java - include negative values in 'catch' block for Double.parseDouble()

Tags: java, try-catch, negative-number

I have a Java client application that can send a message to the server. I am setting up input validation so the client detects whether an acceptable message has been sent on the 'send' button-click.

The messages that should be accepted are anything that can be parsed to a double, or a number of selected strings (recognised by the `string.equals()` method).

I test for the strings first, and if the condition is not met, I try to parse the message to double (`Double.parseDouble(message)`). At this point, I have a `try/catch` block that recognises any failed attept to parse to double (meaning it must contain letters and is therefore invalid), that catches the `NumberFormatException` and allows the user a chance to re-enter the message.

I would now like to make it so that the number cannot be negative, and would like to include this in the same `try/catch` block so that any negative value can give the user the same opportunity to re-enter.

Here is what I currently have:

```
    else
    {   
        try
        {
            //convert number to double (monetary value)
            bidAmount = Double.parseDouble(messageToServer);
            //send to server with item code
            output.println(selectedItemCode + bidAmount);
        }
        //item cannot turned to double
        catch (NumberFormatException numfEx)
        {
            //inform user
            fromServer.setText("Invalid Request!"
                    + USER_PROMPT);
        }
    }
    //clear input field for subsequent entry
    toServer.setText("");
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to implement this rule, without code duplication if at all possible?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `bidAmount = Double.parseDouble(messageToServer);`, we need to add the following:

```
if(bidAmount < 0){
  throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid amount");
}
```

An alternate solution (and probably, best practice) would be to modify catch block to catch `IllegalArgumentException` and throw `IllegalArgumentException` if the amount is less than 0 as shown below:

```
try
        {
            //convert number to double (monetary value)
            bidAmount = Double.parseDouble(messageToServer);
            if(bidAmount < 0){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid amount");
            }
            //send to server with item code
            output.println(selectedItemCode + bidAmount);
        }
        //item cannot turned to double
        catch (IllegalArgumentException numfEx)
        {
            //inform user
            fromServer.setText("Invalid Request!"
                    + USER_PROMPT);
        }
```

Comment: While this certainly works, it is implementing flow control through exceptions, which is arguably a bad idea http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/189222/89303

Comment: @beresfordt point taken. However, it is difficult to derive the 'best' approach from the code snippet provided by OP. While we should not implement flow control through exception, going for another approach might break something else. :)

Comment: Thanks for this, would you mind including an example of the alternate method that you mentioned? Not familiar with this exception or how it works!

Comment: Done. I have added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate method which parses the String to a Double and then checks if it is non-negative, returning null in either invalid case.

```
//convert number to double (monetary value)
bidAmount = getDouble();
if(bidAmount != null) {

    //send to server with item code
    output.println(selectedItemCode + bidAmount);
    toServer.setText("");

} else {
    //item cannot turned to double
    //inform user
    fromServer.setText("Invalid Request!"
            + USER_PROMPT);
}



private Double getDouble() {
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(messageToServer);
        if(d >= 0) {
            return d;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException numfEx) {}
    return null;
}
```

Edit: to say if you are opposed to using null values you could also change the method to return a default negative value, say -1, and then change the condition to check if the double is negative instead of null.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved without relying on exceptions to control the flow of your program, which is generally a bad idea - see discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222/89303)

```
else {   
    // using a tempBidAmount as I don't have enough context to know whether
    // I could just assign the output of parseUserDouble directly to bidAmount
    // without causing issues
    Double tempBidAmount = parseUserDouble(messageToServer);

    if (tempBidAmount != null && tempBidAmount > 0.0) {
        bidAmount = tempBidAmount;
        output.println(selectedItemCode + bidAmount);
    } else {
        fromServer.setText("Invalid Request!" + USER_PROMPT);
    }
}
toServer.setText("");

....

private Double parseUserDouble(Sting userInput) {
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(userInput);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException numfEx) {
        // consider logging here        
    }
    return null;
}
```